# If a string contains 2 words

Tags: php

I'm trying to compare if a string contains 2 words string.

This works:-

```
$list_district = (strpos('1 bed flat in Sekaninova, Prague 2', 'Prague') !== false) ? yes: no ;
```

This not:

```
$list_district = (strpos('1 bed flat in Sekaninova, Prague 2', 'Prague 1') !== false) ? yes: no;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, what is your purpose?

Comment: above code is not correct....can you check and update

Comment: [Working fine here](https://eval.in/738138)   .BTW you have a TYPO mistake in the second code

Comment: @Anant yes indeed. But for some reason, this doesn't work https://eval.in/738187 ... please any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you asked in comment for that do like below:-

```
<?php
$data = '1 bed flat in Sekaninova, Prague 2';
$districts = ["Prague 1","Prague 2"];

foreach ($districts as $district) {
 $district_array = explode(' ',$district);

 $district_string = "(".implode('|',$district_array).")";
 if(preg_match("$district_string", $data) === 1) {
     echo "yes"; 
     echo PHP_EOL; 
 }else{
     echo "no";
 } 

}
```

Output:-https://eval.in/738216

Comment: You're the man, I found out the error was it was looping only on 2 items. The above works on all districts ... about 25 of them.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @Shina  thanks for the appreciation. glad to help you .:):)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (strpos('1 bed flat in Sekaninova, Prague 2', 'Prague 2')) {
    echo district; };
```

Also you can use "stripos" to be case insensitive